# Able to log in Google Play Games, but not showing Leaderboard

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, android-developer-api, google-developers-console

We are developing a smartphone game with my team on Unity, and I'm currently trying to implement Google Play Games in our game, without success.
Right now, the user can log in without issues (popup showing, and logcat says it's ok), but I can't figure why the leaderboard won't show... According to the logcat, the request for the leaderboard seems ok, but no return/error.

I don't think the fault is on Unity side, as the code is the same as the exemple provided by Google :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
#if UNITY_ANDROID
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
#endif
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

public class PlayGameServices_func : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start () 
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
            .RequestEmail()
            .Build();
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
        #endif
    }

    public void ShowLeaderboards() 
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI();
    }

    public void SignIn ()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
            if (success)
                Debug.Log("Successfuly signed in!");
            else 
                Debug.Log("Sign in failed...");
        });
    }

    void SignInCallback (bool success) 
    {
        if (success)
            Debug.Log("Successfuly signed in!");
        else 
            Debug.Log("Sign in failed...");
    }
}
```

I think the problem is on Google Developer Console's side, but after 5 days of searching/experimenting/etc... I wasn't able to find a solution.

Can somebody help me?
Have a nice day !

Comment: Is your game published? or have you uploaded any apk in alpha or beta in google play developer console?

Comment: The game is in Alpha, my mail is registered as tester (I can download the game from the Play store)

Comment: Does your Resources Definition have entry for the leaderboard? You can take a look at this image: https://imgur.com/a/NsmdS

Comment: Yes, it does :)

Comment: Did you follow the setup in the [Creating a leaderboard](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#creating_a_leaderboard)?